# xpath for selecting elements which are not included in a specific list

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xslt variable declared as below:

```
  <xsl:variable name="list">
   <item>Elem1</item>
   <item>Elem2</item>
   <item>Elem3</item>
 </xsl:variable>
```

I need an xpath to match all elements whose local name does not belong in `$list`. I could have opted for `*[not(self::Elem1|self::Elem2|self::Elem3)]` and so on. But I want to declare the variable so that it is easier to maintain later on. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try..........

```
*[not(name()=$list/item)]
```